# How to assign a static IP to Android Emulator

Tags: android, networking, ip, settings, emulation

I need to assign a static IP to my Android 2.2 Emulator. So i checked the  Use static IP option under Wi-Fi settings and provider an Ip and Gateway. But when i checked that in adb shell using ifconfig eth0, its still showing the default IP. It seems I need to set from command line. Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

you can check this link out http://www.ehow.com/how_10006833_change-ip-android-emulator.html

Synopsis from there

**Instructions**

```
    1

    Boot the emulated Android device in the Android emulator.
    2

    Click the "Applications" icon.
    3

    Click "Settings."
    4

    Click "Wireless and Network."
    5

    Click "Wi-Fi Settings."
    6

    Click the "More" button.
    7

    Click "Advanced."
    8

    Click "Use Static IP."
    9

    Click "IP Address" and enter a new IP.
```

Comment: I did the same and even then if I do "eth0", its giving the IP as 10.0.2.15 only. Isn't that IP of my emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

In Android Emulator if you do ifconfig then you will see bridge, eth0 & eth1 as network devices. Where bridge has the 10.0.2.15 as ip and eth0 is up but without any ip and eth1 is down without any ip.

[REFER THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350555/set-ip-address-for-android-emulator)