# How can I change IP in Android emulator

Tags: android, sdk, ip, emulation

Could you please help me, is it possible to change IP in Android emulator (via SDK)? I have to change IP in Android emulator during the testing. Or there is some other soft which can help me?

Comment: What does "change IP in Android emulator" mean?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but it sounds like you want to set the IP address that is being used within the emulator. If that is correct, you might find this solution, from another post, useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350555/set-ip-address-for-android-emulator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1**
Start your Android emulator.

**Step 2**
Click the "Settings" icon.

**Step 3**
Click "Wireless & Networks" and select "Wi-Fi."

**Step 4**
Click "More" and select "Advanced."

**Step 5**
Select the "Use Static IP" button.

**Step 6**
Select "IP Address." Type in the new IP address you wish you use using four dot notation (X.X.X.X). Click "OK" to save the settings.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you coming to this answer in 2020 (using API 29):

1. Head to "Settings" in your Android emulator
2. Select "Network & Internet"
3. Select "Wi-Fi" (should be at the top)
4. Select the Wi-Fi name (should be "AndroidWifi")
5. Select the edit button in the top AppBar (the pencil icon)
6. On the new dialog screen, select "Advanced Options" and then scroll down to where it says "IP Settings." DHCP is probably selected by default, so select that and then change it to "Static"

From there, enter a new IP address (or just random numbers that match the format) in the four dot notation and then select "Save."

**Remember, this device will not use the new IP to access the Internet (it uses your actual IP), but the new IP will show up as the device's IP in testing.**

Comment: Why I do not see "Network & Internet --> Wi-Fi" under Settings? Am on Android Studio 4.0

Comment: @Ranjan are you in the emulator itself? It should be right at the top when you open Settings. You can try searching for it as well.