# Bridge Android Emulator to host for mDNS service discovery

Tags: android, android-emulator, mdns, dns-sd

I created a service on an Adroid TV and I'm currently trying to discover that service from another device using mDSN Service Discovery protocol. When I put the Discovery app on a 2nd device, it was able to detect the service on the 1st TV just fine. But if I put the Discovery app on an android emulator, it can't detect my service on the TV. From all the research I've done, it seems like each Android Emulator is in its own private network and can't really talk to any other devices. I'm not sure how to make this work and I found something that seems like a solution at this link [Set IP Address for Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350555/set-ip-address-for-android-emulator/15415788#15415788), except it didn't work on my machine. My emulator didn't have 2 ethernet interfaces like the example, after the bridging is done, I also lost Internet connection on my host machine. I'm at a loss of what to do. Is this even feasible to get my emulator to detect service on an actual device? If it is, then what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Using `adb forward` to make a port on the emulator accessible from the host
see [more](http://jamiltz.github.io/2016-02-20-running-bonjour-services-with-android-emulator/) on James' Blog

Comment: the link on this answer is broken.

Comment: Use the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20160616164730/http://jamiltz.github.io/2016-02-20-running-bonjour-services-with-android-emulator/